# SQL Command Result to Dictionary C# .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, sql, .net-2.0

I have a simple SQL query (using SqlCommand, SqlTransaction) in .NET 2.0 that returns a table of integer-string pairs (ID, Name).  I want to get this data into a dictionary like `Dictionary<int, string>`.

I can get the result into a DataTable, but even iterating over it, I'm not sure how to do the typing and all that stuff.  I feel like this must be a common problem but I haven't found any good solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Totally intended to put the types...dictionary like dictionary, lol.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try an approach similar to this, adjusted to however you're currently looping over your results:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dictionary.Add(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
    }
}

// do something with dictionary
```

The [SqlDataReader.GetInt32 method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32.aspx) and [SqlDataReader.GetString method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx) would represent the `ID` and `Name` column indices, respectively.

Answer (score 15):

You can return it as a DataReader, and construct the dictionary using linq:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary;
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    dictionary = reader.Cast<DbDataRecord>()
                       .ToDictionary(row => (int)row["id"], row => (string)row["name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
// Define your Dictionary 
IDictionary<int,string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int,string>();

// Read your dataTable 
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) {      
       // Add Id and Name respectively
       dictionary.Add(int.parse(row[0].ToString()),row[1].ToString())           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    IDictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    DataTable mydata = new DataTable("hey");

    foreach (DataRow item in mydata.Rows)
{
    dict.Add(item["id"], item["name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i did not type this in visual studio so you might need to make minor changes to make it run...

```
Dictionary(int key,string value) dictionary = new Dictionary<int key,string value>();

foreach(DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
{
   //null check??
   dictionary.add(Convert.toInt(row[0]),row[1].toString());
}
```

try that ... see if that helps.